# Java: runtime reflection or type introspection?

Tags: java, reflection, introspection

Is the following code considered to be *runtime reflection* or is it *type introspection*?

```java
Class c = java.util.ArrayList.class;
String className = c.getName();
```

I want to use this in the compilation phase, and do not want to use any resources (including time) in runtime. Does it use any runtime resource?

Comment: It does. I don't think there is a compile-time `nameof` in Java (like the one in C#), which seems to be the thing that you are looking for.

Comment: There is no way for this to be processed at compile time in Java.

Comment: Even if you write `String className = "java.util.ArrayList";`, it will consume memory and CPU time at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is both, as @StephenC already points out correctly.

To your request for a compile-time solution: There is a solution, but you'd need to implement your own Builder for that.

## First off, some standard-Java implementations:

Because implementing and including your own Builder might be a lot of work for very little effect, here's a much easier answer: class initialization.

```
public class CompileTimeInit {

    // option 1
    static public final String ARRAYLIST_CLASS_NAME = java.util.ArrayList.class.getName();

    // option 2
    static public final String ARRAYLIST_CLASS_NAME_INIT_BLOCK;
    static {
        ARRAYLIST_CLASS_NAME_INIT_BLOCK = java.util.ArrayList.class.getName();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("1:\t" + ARRAYLIST_CLASS_NAME);

        System.out.println("2:\t" + ARRAYLIST_CLASS_NAME_INIT_BLOCK);

        // option 3
        final Class c = java.util.ArrayList.class;
        final String className = c.getName();
        System.out.println("3:\t" + className);
    }

}
```

static initialization will take its (very minimal) time in class intialization. This is part of the runtime, but it will only take place once a class is referenced/metnioned in some code that gets executed. This initialization will only be done once (per classloader loaded class) and is considered really fast.

## Now, to the real compile-time implementations:

1. You can have really advanced builders implemented, like [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) does, along with integration into IDEs, compilers, build tools, platforms. Check out their page, top menu, "Install", to see the options available.
2. You can write your own builder and include it into the build cycle of your build cycle. The best way to do it is via an [Annotaion "Pre"-Processor](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder).
3. The third option is to write a complete standalone application. This means you have to implement:

- opening .java source files
- scanning for your Interfaces or Annotations
- replacing the code with the calculated contents
- saving .java source files
- let the compilation phase continue

and include that into you build cycle. This is also partially described in the article [above](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder)

Comment: Yes, now it is. I was referring to the comments. You finished your answer while I was typing. I'll correct my statement.

Comment: There is no difference between “option 1” and “option 2”; they even compile to identical bytecode. It’s therefore misleading to put “lazy” into the name of one constant but not the other. Both exhibit the same degree of laziness. After the first time execution, I wouldn’t expect a significant performance difference to “option 3”. In fact, not even writing `String className = "java.util.ArrayList";` will make a significant difference. Making it `final` (compile-time constant) will skip the string concatenation. But `System.out.append("3:\t").println(ArrayList.class.getName());` will do as well.

Comment: Yes. I corrected my code to not call it 'lazy' anymore. And we both agree on the performance part you mentioned: we expect no significant difference there.

Answer (score 2):

I would have said that it is BOTH runtime reflection AND type introspection.

Note that the `[introspection]` tag defines introspection as:

> *"A capability of some object-oriented programming languages to determine the type of an object **at runtime**."*

You could also say that your example uses (runtime) reflection to perform type introspection.

---

> I want to use this in the compilation phase.

It is possible to examine types at compile time in an annotation processor.  However, I suspect that the effort involved in doing that would be prohibitive.  You need to be able to spot a specific pattern in two statements and then replace the statements with something else.

(Have you benchmarked the class name lookup to see how much time it actually takes?  I would have thought it was just a few nanoseconds.  Not enough to be significant.)

Comment: Mostly, it was my theoretical curiosity. I was not hindered pragmatically speaking. I am writing annotation processors and for adding @Generated to the result of all of them wanted a simple general method that can retrieve the name of the calling processor. Any suggestion is welcomed. :)